# Having issues implementing calling this interface

Tags: c#, interface

Can't seem to wrap my head around using an interface sometimes and am stuck trying to call this. Sorry, I realize this should be simple, but the examples I am finding just aren't working.

I have:

```
namespace ApiConnection{
    public interface IRestApiCalls{
        Task<bool> Login(string userName, string password);
    }
}
```

And it's implementation

```
namespace ApiConnection{
    class TestRestApiService : IRestApiCalls    {
        public async Task<bool> Login(string userName, string password){
            //Do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

How would I call Login? I have something similar to:

```
namespace Bll{
    public class Bll : IBll{  //yes, I can call this interface no problem
        public Login(string userName, string password){
            //What goes here to call the IRestApiCalls.Login interface?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not call an interface. An interface simply defines a contract which your class *must* adhere to.

You would call the method just like any other:

```
var myService = new TestRestApiService();
myService.Login("rob", "hunter2");
```

However, since it's an interface, you can *also* write something like this:

```
public void LoginService(IRestApiCalls service)
{
    service.Login("rob", "hunter2");
}
```

Which means you don't care what class you're given, as long as they adhere to the the contract laid out in the interface `IRestApiCall`

Comment: var myService = new TestRestApiService(); gives me the error 'TestRestApiService' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: @VirtualLife You need to make it a public class - this is unrelated to the interface, classes are private unless you explicitly tell it otherwise

Comment: The interface code is not mine. If you are saying it's just wrong, I can go back to the developer on that side, but guessing I am just missing something.

Comment: @VirtualLife Nope, not the interface, your class. `class TestRestApiService : IRestApiCalls    {` should be `public class TestRestApiService : IRestApiCalls    {`

Comment: Understand, sorry wrong wording. The interface and implementation are not mine. So I don't have access to change the code in the ApiConnection namespace. The IRestApiCalls or the TestRestApiService : IRestApiCalls. Sorry, like I said, interfaces still confuse me. So does it need to be public for it to be called? If it is public, doesn't that allow someone to instantiate it directly? Which I thought was the reason not to make it public.

Comment: @VirtualLife Well yes, it allows anyone to instantiate it directly. The above was an example to call it (that is, you can call it normally if you want, and have an instance of the object). If you are not instantiating the object, you need to be given the object. `interface` does not make a method static - you still need an instance to call the method on

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. There is no way to call an interface without it's implementation being public (TestRestApiService)? I had an understanding that there was a way to force someone to use the Interface (ie not allow them to create an instance of the class directly bypassing the interface). That's what I thought the idea was with this code. Guessing I am mistaken tho.

Comment: @VirtualLife No, you can keep `TestRestApiService` as it is. But *something* needs to be able to create the object and pass it to you. There isn't usually a reason to force people to use the interface - that's not interfaces are typically for (and it doesn't give any benefit, really). I think you may be misunderstanding the purpose of interfaces. That being said, you *can* define your method like so: `public async Task<bool> IRestApiCalls.Login(string userName, string password){` which means the object must be cast as `IRestApiCalls` to be callable only when cast as `IRestApiCalls`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111065/discussion-between-virtuallife-and-rob).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you cannot make *your* login method `async`, you could use `WaitAndUnwrapException`:

```
IRestApiCalls rest = ...
var task = rest.Login(userName, password);
var result = task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
if (!result) {
    // Login has failed
}
```

If you have an option of making your own `Login` method `async`, you could `await` the `Login` from the REST object instead:

```
IRestApiCalls rest = ...
var result = await rest.Login(userName, password).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (!result) {
    // Login has failed
}
```

Comment: No option to change the interface in any way unless it's just plain wrong. That is code someone else made that I just need to call. So what you posted makes sense to an extent, but the ... is where I am confused.

Comment: @VirtualLife There needs to be a way to create new `TestRestApiService` - either directly with a `new` operator, through some static method, or through a separate class. You would probably need to pass some parameters to the constructor or to the static method.